# Changing state of icons without waiting for the API response. (Mark as favorite functionality)

Tags: ios, swift, api, favorites

I am creating an app in swift in which i want to implement "mark as favorite" functionality. Basically I have a heart icon which is currently clear. When user taps it it will become orange (just like how the heart icon (like option) in Instagram works)
When I tap the icon, a call goes to the server, and when its success response comes back, the heart icon becomes orange. But this flow takes 3 to 4 seconds average whereas in Instagram, facebook or any other such app this thing happens instantly. Moreover if a user taps the icon repeatedly the counter of likes gets incremented/decremented perfectly, but in my app if I will do that the server calls (simultaneous calls of marking and unmarking an icon) will get collapsed and the app will crash.

I thought of doing it in the following ways:

- When the user taps the icon, change its color instantly without
  waiting for the success response, **assuming** that the success
  response will come. But this isn't a good approach at all because if
  server was unable to process the request (due to any reason) the
  heart will change its color from clear to orange and then again
  clear, which will look very weird.
- Showing an activity indicator up till response comes from the server
  but  again, if the user wants to mark several items from a list, he
  will have to see the indicator and wait for each one of them and it
  will look very clumsy.

So I want a decent solution for my problem. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: User DispatchQueue.main.execute {// Change Your UI after response } thread to change UI of button. Write the code after your response check in Main thread.

Comment: Elaborate what exactly your solution will do, as I am new to iOS

Comment: You are calling API, So it is work with background thread. When API response get back, you need to change UI, So UI always work with main queue. If you change it without main queue, then will take time to change depends on app performance.

Answer (score 1):

First approach with setting icon to orange at request start seems ok from my side, because nobody likes to wait likes to be saved. Look at this case like sending message in chat. You see message in chat immediately after sending, and if it fails to be delivered then it shows corresponding status